# How to prevent inputAccessoryView of a view controller from being shown when an alert is presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, inputaccessoryview

I have a custom `UIViewController` in which I have overridden `inputAccessoryView` to return a view as follows-

```swift
extension LoginViewController {
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        CustomToolbar()
    }
}
```

The `inputAccessoryView` is shown when an `UIAlertController` is presented by the view controller.

Can anyone point out how to prevent `inputAccessoryView` from being shown when an alert is presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check in inputAccessoryView returning logic , and return nil while the alert controller is presented.

```
extension LoginViewController {
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
         if let p = presentedViewController, p.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self) {
                return nil
            }
        CustomToolbar()
     }
}
```

Comment: Generally you should add a few words to explain something about your answer. Code-only answers are frowned-upon on StackOverflow. For example, if someone didn't see the question, would your answer make any sense? Not really. Because of the lack of any explanation, your answer appeared in a review queue to for people to vote on whether it should be deleted. I see the answer is usable but not ideal. Please add a bit of descriptive info.